# Translate Custom Reports and Dashboards name in other language

Tags: dashboard, custom-report-type

```
Hello Sir,

Here I have Problem how can i translate Custom Reports and Dashboards name in other language
I can translate label and field in other language but here i unable to translate Reports and Dashboards name in Other language....

so what can i do to translate these custom reports and Dashboards name...

Here i have snapshots of the problem
```

[image: reports Image]

Here in Snapshot Rounded reports and dashboards name is not translated....

So please help me to translate these name...

Here is the another Dashboard snapshot in that also Dashboard name is not translated...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is almost two years old, but I wanted to share my approach, as I too found the above solution (cloning reports for each language) to be quite daunting in an organization with a large number of supported languages.

Basically, my solution would consist of the following:

1. create default chart for each report (Reports > YOUR_REPORT > Customize > Add Chart) - the charts should resemble the ones used in dashboard
2. create VF page for each chart (report) in the dashboard, and embed the reports' default chart in the VF page using [analytics:reportChart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) component
3. create custom label for title of each report (with as many translations as much languages you wish to support)
4. in the VF page of each report add label reference for each reports' title
5. in the dashboard, instead of using chart components, use your newly created VF pages

You should get something similar to the screenshot below (VF page as dashboard component is used only for right component of the dashboard; upper screenshot is as seen by user with English locale, lower screenshot is as seen by user with German locale):
[image: Localized Report Title in Dashboard]

Code for the VF page is quite simple:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
<style>
.asOfDate{display:none;}
</style>
<div style="border-top:3px solid #861614; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;">
    <h2 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">{!$Label.Report_Title_Planned_Visits_This_Week}</h2>
</div>
<analytics:reportChart reportId="YOUR_REPORT_ID" size="small" showRefreshButton="false"></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Hopefully someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't translate those names.

Check this out:

```
Unfortunately it is not possible to translate Custom Report names in Salesforce however there is a manual workaround to this:

1) Optionally you can create a Report Folder with a title of the required Language (e.g. Brazilian Portuguese)
2) Open the Report whose name you wish to translate
3) Click on "Customize" and then click on "Save" or "Save as" to clone the report
4) Change the Report Name to its translated equivalent and save it in the new folder you just created
```

Comment: If a user with a different preferred language logs into community portal looking at the same dashboard - this manual workaround won't work